# How to prevent access to a Sonos system

Tags: security

I have a Sonos in a pub (although this applies to any public place which shares the wifi).

The router (TP-LINK Archer VR4000) has a guest network and this is locked to not share the local network. It works as expected.

The issue is, when using casting media I can access the speakers directly. This also appears to corrupt the router and after I do this with casting software, I can access the Sonos via the guest network (and as such I am assuming I can see other devices on the network too, although not tested as that is outside the scope of this question)! Sadly, guests are doing this!

Sonos (I think) don't provide any way to restrict access. There is no password on the app or a way (that I know of) to lock the speakers to a single router. As such I am thinking this is quite possibly a more 'common' issue for IoT devices.

Assuming Sonos will not provide this functionality, how do I restrict this as guests are changing the songs.... and there is only so many times I can hear the birdie song!!! :)

Comment: From my (admittedly limited) knowledge of Sonos speakers, I would've thought a separate network would avoid this. Which router are you using that has a 'guest network' setting (model & make would be ideal)? Would it be possible to try just having a separate router altogether for the Sonos?

Comment: @Aurora0001, the issue is the pub streams music from a paid account (such as Napster) and requires internet and there is only 1 line in. A second line may help resolve this though... good idea. Added the router details.

Comment: Looks like a the guest network feature doesn't actually isolate the other users in a completely separate network (as you might have expected), so they're still able to access your Sonos, then. Having a new router just for the Sonos is an awkward, but potentially successful fix. Be sure to post an answer if it works, and if not, [edit] to update.

Answer (score 5):

If it's the same Sonos system I have, you should be able to disable wireless and connect via ethernet to the network. You won't lose any functionality this way.

Otherwise, consider putting a UTM or firewall appliance between the Sonos and your network.

Answer (score 4):

Would be an expense but maybe take a look at installing wireless access points that you can manage what you guests do on your network.

You could put your guests into a "guest only role" so that all they can do is get directed out onto the internet via your wireless network. And add a secondary hidden wireless network that is for your sonos system only.

Perhaps look into Ruckus unleashed access points or Aruba instants. As these allow you to add multiple wireless networks and manage what you want your "guests" or "sonos" clients do.